# What's the most efficient way to find the length of the longest item in a list?

Tags: string, language-agnostic, list, coldfusion, code-golf

Given a list of assorted length words, what is the best way to find the maximum length of any words?

For example, the following should return 6

```
findMaxLen("a,set,of,random,words")
```

Of course, it's fairly trivial to do this...

```
<cffunction name="findMaxLen" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfset var CurMax = 0 />
    <cfset var CurItem = 0 />
    <cfloop index="CurItem" list="#Arguments[1]#">
        <cfif Len(CurItem) GT CurMax >
            <cfset CurMax = Len(CurItem)/>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn CurMax />
</cffunction>
```

Or, a little shorter...

```
<cffunction name="findMaxLen" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfset var CurMax = 0 />
    <cfset var CurItem = 0 />
    <cfloop index="CurItem" list="#Arguments[1]#">
        <cfset CurMax = Max( CurMax , Len(CurItem) ) />
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn CurMax />
</cffunction>
```

But is there a better way - something more efficient?

Perhaps some Java method? Converting to array and sorting by item length? Counting the biggest gap between commas?

In practical terms, either of the above two examples will work fine for my current need, and this isn't for something that is performance critical, so I don't *need* an answer to this, but I thought it would still be interesting to see what people might come up with...

Comment: I just have to interject at this point: xml-based languages are an abomination :)

Comment: CFML is tag-based, *not* XML-based. All but the cffunction tags above would have an XML parser complaining.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Count the distance between commas.

I don't think anything *could* be faster than that; it's `O(n)`, and you *have* to look at each character at least once anyway (to see if it's a comma).

```
int FindLongestWord(char* str)
{
   char* lastComma = str - 1;
   int longest = 0;
   int length;
   char* pCheckChar;

   for(pCheckChar = str; *pCheckChar; pCheckChar++)
   {
      if(*pCheckChar == ',')
      {
         length = pCheckChar - lastComma - 1;
         if(length > longest)
         {
            longest = length;
         }

         lastComma = pCheckChar;
      }
   }

   // Check to see if the last word is the longest
   length = pCheckChar - lastComma - 1;
   if(length > longest)
   {
      longest = length;
   }

   return longest;
}
```

or I suppose you could just say

```
"a,set,of,random,words".Split(',').Max(w=>w.Length);
```

if we're playing games... ;]

Comment: @sfossen: why, can't you do it yourself? ;-)

Comment: I could do it too, but I'm not wanting my answer accepted either.  But, really, I could.  Honest.

Comment: small error, lastComma is only updated on longest match. should be below the 2nd if.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl (assuming we have a variable `$max` in which the answer is to be stored):

```
(length $1 > $max) && ($max = length $1) while "a,set,of,random,words" =~ /(\w+)/g;
```

Or:

```
(length $_ > $max) && ($max = length $_) foreach split /,/, "a,set,of,random,words";
```

Or:

```
$max = length((sort { length $b <=> length $a } split /,/, "a,set,of,random,words")[0]);
```

TMTOWTDI, after all.

EDIT: I forgot about the Core Modules!

```
use List::Util 'reduce';
$max = length reduce { length $a > length $b ? $a : $b } split /,/, "a,set,of,random,words";
```

...which somehow manages to be longer than the other ones. Oh well!

EDIT 2: I just remembered `map()`:

```
use List::Util 'max';
$max = max map length, split /,/, "a,set,of,random,words";
```

*That's* more like what I'm looking for.

EDIT 3: And just for completeness:

```
($max) = sort { $b <=> $a } map length, split /,/, "a,set,of,random,words";
```

Comment: I'd just like to note that there are probably better ways to do these, but I thought I'd go ahead and get them out there.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there's a `code-golf` tag, here's 52 characters in C#

```
"a,set,of,random,words".Split(',').Max(w=>w.Length);
```

Comment: I guess we both thought to drop the `String.` at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

And here's the 'short' CFML way - 72 chars...

```
Len(ArrayMax("a,set,of,random,words".replaceAll('[^,]','1').split(',')))
```

Another version, 78 chars but handles huge strings (see comments)...

```
Len(ListLast(ListSort("a,set,of,random,words".replaceAll('[^,]','1'),'text')))
```

Comment: 72, if you use "set" instead of "series"

Comment: Oops, should have c&p-ed rather than re-typing. Ta.

Comment: I know nothing about CFML; Does that work for strings of any length?  (e.g. a 1000 length string with no commas)  I'm wondering if ArrayMax actually does the conversion from the 111s to a numeric data type...

Comment: You're correct - ArrayMax gives the maximum number, so it is converting each string into a number, and is failing somewhere between 300 and 400 long.

A similar List-based sorting version (added above) works with large values though, if very slowly - does 10,000,006 in approx 6.6 seconds.

Comment: (For comparison, the same 10M are processed in ~60-125ms by the two original functions in the question)

Comment: @Peter: I wonder if the "between 300 and 400" is the limit of a 64-bit double (goes to about 1.8e308) ...

Comment: @Peter: So is the method actually returning the correct "longest word", or is it the length of the string representation of a double?  (i.e. Is it returning 309 as the length longest word, or the length of the string "1.000e309")

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct value upto 309, (but returns 1 for 310 and over).
That's the length of the longest word. The whole string is actually 358/359 chars and can be made longer with no problems once the longest word doesn't exceed 309.

Comment: This is the source string I'm testing that with:
- I'm using this: "a,set,of,random,words,with,#RepeatString('a',309)#,really,long,one,in,it"

Answer (score 0):

I did see the code golf tag - here is 54 characters in Python:

```
len(max("a,set,of,random,words".split(","), key=len))
```

Comment: Try max(map(len,"a,set,of,random,words".split(",")))

52

Comment: Didn't necessarily mean it in least characters sense, but fair enough.  :)
Could you save a char by dropping the space before key?

Comment: Actually, @recursive, that's 48 characters. :-)

Comment: @recursive - you beat me - very nice!

Answer (score 0):

In java without string extra functions. (just a pseudo linked list :P) Give max as 0 in the begining

```
   int find(LinkedList strings, int max) {
      int i;
      String s=(String)strings.element();
      for(i=0;s.charAt(i)!='\0';i++);
      if(strings.hasNext())
         return find(strings.Next(),(i>max?i:max));
      return max;
    }
```

Edit: Just noticed now it's given a String of words not a list of strings, well never mind stays here the same :)

Comment: Java doesn't have null-terminated strings; charAt will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException instead. Try going up to s.length() instead.

Comment: I didn't want to use string functions then it would loose the fun of it, then it's a bit mixed with c

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about readability... ;)

```
String longest(String...ss){String _="";for(String s:ss)if(_.length()<s.length())_=s;return _;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it depends on what efficient means.  if it means the least amount of characters in the code written, that is one thing.  if it means, least amount of memory or fastest executing, that is another.

for fastest executing i'll take the loop.

Answer (score 0):

in vc++

```
int findMaxLen(const char *s)
{
    const char c = ',';
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    while(*s)
    {
        while(*s && *s++ != c)b++;
        if(b > a)a=b;
        b = 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## In [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/)

Assume list of boxed strings(L):

```
{.\:~>#&.>L
```

An example using a CSV file:

```
{.\:~;>#&.>readcsv'test.csv'
```

Comment: Shorter: >./@:(#@>)  For example: >./@:(#@>)'Hello';'world!'

Answer (score 0):

In scala (55 chars):

```
",set,of,random,words".split(",").:\(0)(_.length max _)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clojure: 49 bytes.

```
(def l #(reduce max(for[x(.split%%2)](count x))))
```

Legible version:

```
(defn longest [astr sep]
  (reduce max
    (for [word (.split astr sep)]
      (count word))))
```

I'm still learning the language, so I'd love to hear any ways to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Python in front of me so I can't check this works, but...

```
def maxlen(x):
    return len(sorted(x.split(), key=lambda y: len(y))[1])
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be simplest?

```
<cffunction name="findMaxLen" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfset longest = 0>
    <cfloop list="#Arguments[1]#" index="w">
        <cfif len(w) gt longest>
            <cfset longest = len(w)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn longest>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: This method was already posted in the original question. You may have missed the [`[code-golf]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info) tag (now deprecated) - 249 chars including white space ;-).